# Hibernate, Spring, querying in non-managed bean causes SessionException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a simple entity - Team, with name and rating properties (or maybe more).
Suppose I need to query my teams by multiple criteria.
So instead of adding multiple methods with signature like 'findByXYZAndZYX' to my service, I'd rather add following method :

```
Teams findTeams()
```

Implementation snippet:

```
@Autowired private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
...
@Override
public Teams getTeams() {
    return new HibernateTeams(sessionFactory);
}
```

Now, Teams interface:

```
public interface Teams extends Iterable<Team> {

    Teams withNameContaining(String name);
    Teams withRatingGreaterThan(Integer rating);
}
```

and hibernate-specific implementation:

```
public class HibernateTeams implements Teams {

    private static final String NAME_PROPERTY = "name";
    private static final String RATING_PROPERTY = "rating";

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Criteria criteria;

    public HibernateTeams(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        criteria = getRootCriteria();
    }

    private Criteria getRootCriteria() {
        return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Team.class);
    }

    @Override
    public HibernateTeams withNameContaining(String name) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like(NAME_PROPERTY, name));
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Teams withRatingGreaterThan(Integer rating) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.gt(RATING_PROPERTY, rating));
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Team> iterator() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Collection<Team> result = criteria.list();
        return result.iterator();
    }

    private Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

But now, using this in client code:

```
teamService
.getTeams()
.withNameContaining("someTeamName")
.withRatingGreaterThan(15)
```

I have an SessionException

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed
```

I suppose this happens because of passing sessionFactory to non-managed class.

So there are a couple of questions here:

1) Is it possible to do this the way I wrote it? I tried to annotate my HibernateTeams with Transactional or sth, but it didn't help.

2) If I need to make my HibernateTeams spring-managed-bean and possibly inject SessionFactory into it, how can I do that? I've already tried with 
`@Component @Scope("prototype")`
or `@Configurable`
but with no luck.

Thanks,

Comment: Use `Specification` which can be executed by the `JpaSpecificationExecutor`. That way you have a `findAll(Specification )` method. You can pass in whatever you like. I assume that you use `spring-data-jpa` here btw.

Comment: So it looks like I was reinventing a wheel once again. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so I've implemented spring-data-jpa with querydsl solution and it works fine. But back to my code - when I pass jpa's EntityManager instead of Hibernate SessionFactory, everything works just fine. What's so special about Hibernate SessionFactory, that it causes so much problems?